# page not loading in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have got a button with an onclick javascript event that does some form validation. If the validation fails, false is returned. Otherwise nothing is returned, and the form should be submitted.

But what's happening is the url loads in the address bar but the page never loads. No headers are sent, no error messages display. Just a blank page.

This seems to only happen in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you closed all your tags in the top of the page. In particular the head tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a self-closing script tag.

In IE, this causes an issue, which can result in an completely blank page.

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-153-self-closing-script-tag-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you call submit() if validation passes?